# ember 1.0.0 semantic commands in controller or own routes

Tags: ember.js

I have a small testproject (which is not ready yet) for an ember CRUD application with a master detail view and a one to many relation. (https://github.com/erhard/emb_boot.git)
As in Rails I put all my methods like new edit or delete in the controller from there I fire up a modal screen for the input fields and store the data in a global data object which I want to synchronize with the server later with put post or delete.
So I have semantic methods in the controller, quite natural for me.

Now I saw in the ember doc something like extra routes for new or edit.
Like for example

```
@.resource order, ->
    @.route new
    @.route edit
```

and so on also with the heavy logic behind it (http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/)

Now I am not sure which way to go with ember. Whats best or recommended  The Rails Way  or is there a new ember way ?

Any hints are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would recommend start separating your Rails concepts from
Ember. MVC means different things both in Ember and Rails, as Rails
developer I also try to look for analogies and sometimes can get
confusing (I'm working on a simple community guide for Rails devs into
Ember https://github.com/abuiles/ember-rails-style-guide)

In Ember, the way to keep those "semantic methods" is done with Routes.

In your case you'd have the OrdersIndexRoute, OrdersNewRoute, OrdersEditRoute
(think of each of this ones as the "actions" in Rails) where

OrdersIndexRoute = index action, you will need to setup all your
orders models to be listed. It will look something like

```
App.OrdersIndexRoute = Ember.Route.Extend({
  model: function(){
      return Order.all; // If you are using ember-data this would be different, just supposing Orders.all returns all your orders models.
  }
});
```

OrdersNewRoute = new action, you will need to setup a `new` object
which will be bound to the form and then submitted to your server.

```
App.OrdersNewRoute = Ember.Route.Extend({
    model: function(params){
        return Order.new() // returns a new instance of your model
    },
    actions: {
        // this means that you would have something in your template like <button {{action this}}>...
        save: function(model){
            model.save()
        }
    }
});
```

OrdersEditRoute = edit action, the `model` here would be the one that
you want to edit.

```
App.OrdersEditRoute = Ember.Route.Extend({
    model: function(params){
        return Order.find(params.id)
    },
    actions: {
        save: function(model){
            model.save()
        }
    }
});
```

When you have this kind of doubt, feel free to jump into #emberjs in IRC, lots of smart and helpful fools there, willing to give you a hand when need it.

Comment: Thanks this answer solved my question. It explained it very good. I dont feel comfortable with this style of architecture. The reason is explained here http://erhardtechnicalblog.blogspot.de/2013/10/uncomfortable-pattern-in-emberjs.html   (the place here is not enougth.

Comment: Now I found a video of yehunda katz(one of a main ember developer) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u6RFyVN9sNg at min. 37 there is an example. He did not make it like you suggested with an own edit route . He made it exact like I did.... just with an action in the controller "edit".

Answer (score 0):

In ember groups of routes work with a single resource.  Each route has it's own controller though.  This helps avoid cluttering editing routes controllers with display route controllers logic and vice versa.

I'm sure you've already read this, but for future people coming here, http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/.